# How to display last data entry of nested array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, google-sheets

Want to start by saying I'm very new to Javascript (and admittedly don't have much experience with coding), so wanted to apologise upfront for what's probably a basic question. I can confirm I **have** used the search function and literally spent all of yesterday trying to find an answer that would apply here.

I currently have a continuously updating Google Sheets document which I'm using as a JSON backend. I'm using Ajax via jQuery to pull the data to the page.

What I'm trying to accomplish is have the page display the number of rows contained within the Google Sheet document (this number will be continuously increasing as it is using live information). So for example, if there are 2000 rows of data within the spreadsheet, the page would display 2000. I have looked into the JSON structure of the sheets data [and it seems to be nested twice over.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz8qB.png)

What I'm assuming needs to be done is get the last "row" entry recorded. I guess the next hurdle after this is how to add the sums of two separate sheets.

All I have so far is this:

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


function getData(json) {
            console.log(json);
        }

    </script>

    <script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/10sLn2tlNGINp0mVi2rlnuxi7k2c5jWdNz4eJNbgAE9E/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=getData">
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to show this value using this approach

```
var data = {obj:{gs$cell:{row:'2000',col:'4'}}}

function getData(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  var $span = $('<span>',{
    text:data.obj.gs$cell.row
  });
    $('body').append($span);
}
```

**---EDIT----**

Adding [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/smjbngoa/). Using it I hope you will be able to understand how JSON works and looks. Also I suggest to document yourself using this [simplified article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp). Have a good day!

Comment: Big thanks for giving a bit of help! I can see from the console the stringify part is working but I'm getting an error message with the rest: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gs$cell' of undefined_

Comment: @MrLatvia add to your question your example JSON and I will help you. You are getting this exception because you don't have obj property in your json.

Comment: I've just updated the post for you. I've been trying to learn and understand the syntax of JSON but don't know whats meant by object in this case as I thought it would be whats nested within the array.

Comment: @MrLatvia I edited my answer too. I added jsfiddle link to it.

Comment: forgot to thank you for this. The jsfiddle solution worked in the end!